# How to calculate $\nabla\cdot (|L_{\perp}| \vec{v})$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, velocity, flow, calculus

Let's assume I know $\nabla\cdot (|L_{x}| \vec{v})$ and $\nabla\cdot (|L_{y}| \vec{v})$, where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity field and $L_x$ and $L_y$ represent classical angular momentum components in $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ (unit vectors) direction of usual cartesian coordinate system.

Also, $\vec{L_{\perp}}$ = $L_x \hat{x}$ + $L_y \hat{y}$, and $|L_{\perp}|$ = $\sqrt{L_x^2 + L_y^2}$.

I wonder, knowing all the above info, how can I calculate $\nabla\cdot (L_{\perp} \vec{v})$ in terms of known $\nabla\cdot (|L_{x}| \vec{v})$ and $\nabla\cdot (|L_{y}| \vec{v})$?

Comment: Yeah, but because of the square root, problem becomes non-trivial too fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be overwhelmed by notation. Simplify to
$|L_{x}| =b$, $|L_{y}| = c$, $|L_{\perp}|=a$, so
$$
a^2=b^2+c^2, 
$$
hence
$$
b\nabla \cdot (b\vec v) =b^2 \nabla \cdot \vec v +  \vec v\cdot \nabla b^2/2,  
$$
etc. Consequently, by elementary vector calculus,
$$
a\nabla \cdot (a\vec v) =b\nabla \cdot (b\vec v) +c\nabla \cdot (c\vec v),  
$$
where you have *a,b,c*; normalize by *a*, now.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right! I was overwhelmed by the notation. It worked out perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

If $L_{x}$ and $L_{y}$ are constants independent of the coordinates, the answer is yes. Just use the following identity to prove it:
$$ \overrightarrow{ \nabla }  \big( \lambda  \overrightarrow{V} \big)=\overrightarrow{V}.  \overrightarrow{ \nabla }  \big( \lambda \big) +\lambda   \overrightarrow{ \nabla }.\overrightarrow{V}$$
If $L_{x}$ and $L_{y}$ are functions, then the answer is in general no.

Comment: No, $L_x$ and $L_y$ are not constants. In addition, I want to represent $\nabla\cdot (|L_{\perp}|\vec{v})$ in terms of $\nabla\cdot (|L_{x}|\vec{v})$ and $\nabla\cdot (|L_{y}|\vec{v})$